# How to set "without overwrite" option when using FileUtils.mv

Tags: ruby

I want to move files if the files not exist.
With `system("mv -n foo.txt bar.txt")` is basically what I want.
But I prefer not to use `system`, because it depends environment.

Is there corresponding option for `mv -n` in `FileUtils.mv`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) for `FileUtils.mv`, it seems there is no single-command equivalent to `mv -n`. The supported option flags are `:verbose`, `:secure`, `:noop` and `:force`.

You can work round this with a check if the target exists, e.g.

```
unless File.exists?( target )
  FileUtils.mv source, target
end
```